# Can I use awk to specify in which column to place string?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a tab separated text file called test.txt with multiple columns that I'm trying to make identical to another file called output.txt.

The test.txt looks as follows

```
    t   m  sx  sy  sz  rx   ry   rz

49.07   0   -1.00   0.00   -0.11   20.00   0.00   -2.18

49.47   0   -1.00   0.00   -0.11   22.00   0.00   -2.33

50.89   0   -1.00   0.00   -0.11   34.00   0.00   -3.21

.
:

42.06  0    29.00   0.00   -2.86   12.00   0.00   -1.44
```

The problem is that, no matter what type of delimiter I use, still it will not have the same form as the desired output file called output.txt

In the output.txt, all these columns have a specific location, so

```
    t        m     sx      sy        sz      rx       ry     rz
Ln1,col1    Ln1,col9    Ln1,col17    Ln1,col25    Ln1,col33  Ln1,col41  Ln1,col49 Ln1,col57
```

I'm a bit new with awk, sed and most of other unix commands. Any suggestion?

Comment: I just put the header column for explanation purpose. The original file has no headers, only numeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like this?

```
awk -F 'BEGIN{print "t\tm\tsx\tsy\tsz\trx\try\trz"}{print $1"\t"$9"\t"$17"\t"$25"\t"$33"\t"$41"\t"$49}' test.txt
```

You print the header at the beginning and then for each line you print the desired columns

Comment: Tried your advice without headers and to pipe it in an output file, but no luck. :(

Comment: In the most simplest form I would like to do smth like this: take column 1 from test.txt and pipe it into output.txt on the column 1. Then take column 2 from the test.txt and pipe it into output.txt column 9. So, each column from the test.txt should be placed on a specific location in the output.txt, where the location is defined bu the column number. Probably without any delimiters, since there are empty columns in the output file?

Comment: What exact position do you want for test columns in the output file?

Comment: Managed to use a certain number of spaces between each column to get the desired output. Now I just need to find the way to use the left alignment for each column.                                    awk '{print $1"   "$2"    "$3"   "$4"    "$5"   "$6"    "$7"    "$8}' test.txt > output.txt

Comment: I think that AWK/GAWK printf can do the job if you change a little your code:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html

Comment: Thanks, printf did the job. :)

Answer (score 0):

example for `printf`:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf(\"%-9s\", $i); print}' file
```

[more examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html)